# Mean value theorem question

Tags: calculus

So I have to prove that the equation $e^x=x+1$ does not have any real roots except $x=0$. Do I use Lagrange or Cauchy?

Answer (score 2):

Put $f(x) = e^x - x - 1$. Hence $f'(x) = e^x - 1$. The function is strictly decreasing when $x < 0$ and strictly increasing when $x > 0$. Since $f(0) = 0$, this is the only real root it can take.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to choose between such able men. Let $f(x)=e^x-(x+1)$.

We have $f(0)=0$. Note that $f'(x)=e^x-1$.

So $f'(x)\lt 0$ if $x\lt 0$, and $f'(x)\gt 0$ if $x\gt 0$.

It follows that $f$ is decreasing in the interval $(-\infty,0)$, and increasing in the interval $(0,\infty)$. Thus $f$ can only be $0$ at $x=0$.

**Remark:** The usual proof that if $f'(x)\gt 0$ in an intervalm then $f$ is increasing in that interval uses the ordinary MVT of a first course in calculus.

We can rewrite the above proof so that the "increasing function" theorem is not mentioned. It is unfortunately convenient to separate the proof into two cases, (i) $x$ positive amd (ii) $x$ negative. We do (i). By the MVT,
$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(c)$$
for some $c$ strictly between $0$ and $x$. It follows that $f(x)-f(0)=xf'(c)$.

But
 $f'(c)=e^c-1\gt 0$. Thus $f(x)-f(0)\gt 0$. But  $f(x)-f(0)=e^x-(x+1)$. Thus $e^x-(x+1)\gt 0$, and therefore $e^x\gt x+1$.